# Increment a static variable in object before returning that object

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have some code that creates Objects called Weights. Now there are subclasses of these Weights called - WeightSmall, WeightMedium, and WeightLarge - each with their own static variable called onScreen. This variable should increment when one of either WeightSmall, WeightMedium or WeightLarge is added, however these get return on the call of the create method rather than being added to an array. I have an array of Weight objects - is there a way to access what subclass type an element is in the array of the parent class?

Here is the code for creating weights:

```
public Weight createWeight() {
    decider = Math.random() * 1;
    // creates rocks randomly with the lowest chance for l, and the highest chance for m
    if (decider <= 0.33) {
        // small weight
        return new WeightSmall(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.weight_s), new Random().nextInt(screenWidth), -10);
    } else if (decider <= 0.5 && decider > 0.33) {
        // large weight
        return new WeightLarge(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.weight_l), new Random().nextInt(screenWidth), -10);
    } else {
        // medium weight
        return new WeightMedium(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.weight_m), new Random().nextInt(screenWidth), -10);
    }
}
```

What needs to happen is for WeightSmall lets say, it needs to check WeightSmalls onScreen variable to see if it's smaller than, let's say 3. if it is return the weight. However I can't think of a way to access WeightSmall's onScreen variable as it needs to be created more than once and I tried implement them into an ArrayList but it causes complications in the update method. Here is the rest of the code (that matters) for the class:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        player.draw(canvas);
        Weight[] weightArray = weights.toArray(new Weight[0]);
        for (Weight weight : weightArray) {
            weight.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}

// updates the weight's position on the screen and checks collision with the player
public void update() {
    Weight[] weightArray = weights.toArray(new Weight[0]);
    for (Weight weight : weightArray) {
        weight.update();
        if (weight.getBounds().intersect(player.getBounds())) {
            player.setTouched(false);
            Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(this.getContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
            this.getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
        }
    }
}

// count down timer spawning weights in every tick
public void timer() {
    if (start == true) {
        if (weightSpawnTimer != null) {
            weightSpawnTimer.cancel();
            weightSpawnTimer = null;
        }
        weightSpawnTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 800) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                weights.add(createWeight());
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                weightSpawnTimer.start();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Edit for clarity: What I need to happen, is in the onTick method, check if the subclass of weight's onScreen variable is <= 3, if it is, create a new weight, if it isn't do nothing. Once the weight is then offscreen, decrement this variable so new weights of that subclass can then be created.

Comment: You are trying to count the number of each subclasses which are on screen right?

Comment: If so, simply declare a static integer in each Weight* subclass.  In the Weight superclass, declare a method called `getNumberOnScreen`.  This is over-ridden by the subclass to return the value for the specific subclass.

Comment: Yes correct. Okay so I've implemented what you've said, but where do I go from here to call this method to check each type of Weight?

Edit: as in I can do the following:
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     Weight[] weightArray = weights.toArray(new Weight[0]);
     for (Weight weight : weightArray) {
      if (weight.getOnScreen() <= 3) {
       weights.add(createWeight());
      }
     }
    }

But will this pick up the correct onScreen variable depending on the subclass of Weight added? Also how would I then decrement this variable once the objects done?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
class WeightSmall {
    public WeightSmall(...) {
        // increment static
    }
}
```

Let each class be responsible to increment it's own number in case an instance is created.

Modifying a `static` variable from an instance is usually considered bad practice. The few legit use-cases are typically some sort of instance counting. At least when you don't count down.

Counting down is where the trouble starts because Objects do have a defined start but their end is not guaranteed. You can count down in `finalize` - i.e. when the garbage collector has found your instance - but that's not guaranteed to happen soon or at all. Using that to find out how many instances are on screen would correlate to the actual number but could be completely wrong.

So in a case when you want to know how many objects you show on screen you must actively count that number down once the place responsible for showing the objects let's go of one.
And since that is already a responsibility for the class that wants to know how many objects are on screen, it should as well keep track of the numbers in a local variable of it's own.

By using a `static` property you limit yourself to have just 1 screen. If you let the other place count the number you don't limit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Static variable initialized at 0, then on the constructor your make it +1